# Akka streams register flow same signature

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a doubt regarding if it would be possible to register multiple flows with the same signature having been resolve through dependency injection

```
class Application @Inject()(
     source: Source,
     intermediateFlows: Seq[Flow[Int, Int, Any]],
     sink: Sink,
     materializer: ActorMaterializer) {

   def run(): Unit = {
      source
       ...
       .runWith(sink)(materializer)
   }
}
```

So the idea I have been exploring, more than looking at the API, is using a forEach to accumulate the flows and after do a single via (as there does not seem to be a via collection). But i have not manage to make this work.

Has anyone achieved this before? Is this a bad idea? Have i missed something in the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for something like `fold`

```
val combinedFlow = intermediateFlows.fold(Flow[Int])(_ via _)

source.via(combinedFlow).runWith(sink)(materializer)
```

Note that this would work only if

- your flows are having the same input and output types
- you don't care about the flows materialized value

Comment: awesome :D... i will give it a try in a second